# Fresh Installation of MySql: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES) (MacOS)

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I have just installed MySQL on MacOS and I cannot login to the database in either terminal or workbench. I'm not sure how to solve this issue.

> Your connection attempt failed for user 'root' to the MySQL server at localhost:3306: 
> Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Comment: Maybe this answer could help you. => https://stackoverflow.com/a/22851247/6656323

Answer (score 1):

Just type this in the terminal:

```
sudo -i
```

You'd be taken to the root terminal and then access the databases with the command

```
mysql -u root
```

That's it now do whatever you want to do.